# Rounding numbers on AVRs in C

Tags: c, avr, atmega

I am writing code for an AVR (in C) to continuously change the duty cycle of three PWM channels. To do this, I wrote a function that takes in a value *as a percentage* and sets certain registers to certain values determined by the percentage and the TOP value of the timer. Pseudo-code for this --

```
register = (int) (duty / 100 * timer_top);
```

But, unless duty = 100, this doesn't work (there is no PWM output).

I tried using the round() function in math.h, but that, too, gives similar output, and makes the compiled files unnecessarily large. I tried other methods, like --

```
register = duty / 100 * timer_top
register = (duty / 100 * timer_top) + 0.5
register = (int) (duty / 100 * timer_top) + 0.5
```

But none work. Could someone please help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: Just making sure: did you mean (duty/100)*timer_top or (duty/timer_top)*100?

Comment: What is the type of `duty` and `timer_top`? And what is their values? Remember that if `duty` is an integer and less than `100` then `duty / 100` will be zero.

Comment: That is clearly not your actual code, since it won't compile ... Please try to be as accurate as possible when asking questions, the more guessing we have to do the harder it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `duty` is an integer, then `duty / 100` will be the *integer* quotient, i.e. truncated to an integer, which will be zero for `duty` < 100. The computationally cheapest way to avoid this is performing the multiplication first, like

```
register = duty * timer_top / 100;
```

If you want to do real floating-point division, you can write that as

```
register = (int) (duty / 100. * timer_top);
```

where the decimal point in the constant makes it a double value. In this case, you can also use the other alternatives you wrote to affect rounding behaviour. But you can get different rounding behaviour using integer divisions only as well, e.g.

```
register = (duty*timer_top + 50)/100;
```

which will round to nearest instead of to zero, just like your `+ 0.5` would in the double-valued approach.

Comment: Add 0.5 to a float and cast it to an uint is genius, isn't it? For rounding unsigned. Thanks, MvG !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Register = (long long)duty * timer_top / 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a rough version of rounding function using integer math only. The following pseudocode assumes that all numbers are positive:

```
intermediate = 100 * timer_top
register = duty/intermediate;
if (duty%intermediate>intermediate/2) {
    register++;
}
```